# Reusing Python object to add different data to list of objects

Tags: python, csv

Alright, here goes: I have a custom class that I've created to store multiple fields in columnar data as I iterate over the contents of a file line-by-line. I'm wanting to reuse one object each time, adding items to its fields one at a time and then adding this object to a list before running a method that resets all the fields to an empty string. I'll show you a simplified version of what my code is doing.

```
class MyClass:
    firstName = ""
    middleName = ""
    lastName = ""
    def clearAllFields(self):
        self.firstName = ""
        self.middleName = ""
        self.lastName = ""

myClassImpl = MyClass()
nameData = []
for current in open('nameList.csv','r'):
    current = current.split(',')
    myClassImpl.firstName = current[0]
    myClassImpl.middleName = current[1]
    myClassImpl.laststName = current[2]
    nameData.append(myClassImpl)
    myClassImpl.clearAllFields()
for item in nameData:
    print item.firstName
```

Problem is, the output for this code is the first name for the last person in the list, repeated once for every line in the file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot re-use an instance like this; you are modifying the *same object* over and over again. `nameData.append(myClassImpl)` adds a *reference* to the list, not a copy. In the end, you have a list of references all pointing to the same single copy, which will only show the very last change you made.

Create a new instance for every row instead:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, first, middle, last):
        self.firstName = first
        self.middleName = middle
        self.lastName = last

for current in open('nameList.csv','r'):
    current = current.split(',')
    myClassImple = MyClass(*current)
    nameData.append(myClassImpl)
```

or use a [`collections.namedtuple()` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Even better, use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read the CSV data instead of parsing it yourself:

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple

MyClass = namedtuple('MyClass', 'firstName middleName lastName')

with open('nameList.csv','r') as infh:
    nameData = [MyClass(*row) for row in csv.reader(infh)]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! Python's not my first language. :) I actually can't use a constructor like that; the data I'm using is on a varying number of separate lines per record, so I'm having to run a regex on each line and handle a multitude of flags to determine which fields have passed, which are still coming, and when a record is complete. That having been said, I added a "new object" line to the case for a new record and it worked like a charm. Thanks again!